# Creating a range of objects at once in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a set of numbers and I want to save each of them in the database. My approach is:

```
class NbrSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    last_number = Nbr.objects.order_by("-number").first().number
    start_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True, initial=last_number+1)
    end_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True, initial=last_number+1)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Nbr
        fields = ["start_number", "end_number", ...]
        exclude = ["number"]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        s = int(cleaned_data["start_number"])
        e = int(cleaned_data["end_number"]) + 1
        self.number_list = [n for n in range(s, e)]
        
    def save(self, commit=False):
        for n in self.number_list:
            print("number to create", number)
            instance = Nbr.objects.create(number=n, ...)
        print("all done", instance)
        return super.save(self)
```

model:

```
class Nbr(models.Model):
    number = models.BigIntegerField() # not unique!
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    somefield = models.ForeignKey(...)
    someotherfield = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    ...
```

I can see the output of both of the `print` statements in the console (`number` has a reasonable value here). But nothing is saved to the database and I get an `IntegretyError` from the `return super().save(self)` statement (I guess it's this one) saying: `NOT NULL constraint failed: app_nbr.number`.

So far I tried:

1. creating a list of `Nbr` instances, `bulk_create` the list and returning the list -> `'list' object has no attribute 'save'`
2. same as above but just returning the last `instance` -> `'NbrSetForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'. Did you mean: '_save_m2m'?` (I have no many2many relations in my model)

Comment: Can you provide the code of the "Nbr" model?

Comment: I added the model, or the relevant part of it, though I am not sure how that may help (it's super simple).

Answer (score 0):

the issue you are facing seems to come from the fact that you are trying to save `Nbr` objects directly within the `NbrSetForm` class without specifying the `number` field and django is raising an `IntegrityError` because the `number` field cannot be null according to your modeldefinition.

you should create and save the `Nbr` instances within the `save` method of the form so your `save` method should be like this:

```
class NbrSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your other methods

        def save(self, commit=False):
        instance_list = []
        for n in self.number_list:
            instance = Nbr(number=n, ...)  # Add the appropriate field values
            instance.save()
            instance_list.append(instance)
        print("all done", instance_list)
        return instance_list
```

make sure the fields you are excluding from the form are note required fields in the `Nbr` model.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: After trying I get an `AttributeError` thrown at me: `'list' object has no attribute 'save'`. Is this because of the `return instance_list`?

Comment: the primary key ```id``` being automatically generated and managed by the database, when using ```bulk_create``` in django the primary key generation is not handled automatically and you need to make sure that primary keys are unique.

I have edited the answer and modified ```Nbr``` model to allow the ```id``` field to be generated automatically by django.

Comment: But I do not want to make `number` a unique field. It is not the pk of the model. That's what it's `id` is for?

Comment: I've changed the answer again, I hope this time everything works out :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort - but this still returns a list, and not a object that can be saved. Thus the error message stays the same: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'save'`.

Comment: What I did now (and it works) is the following: create all instances and save them, call super and return the last one: `for n in self.number_list:` `instance = Nbr(number=n ...)` `instance.save()` `super(NbrSetForm).save(commit=False)` `return instance`
if you want, please alter your answer and I will accept it, as I think you helped me a lot on the way.